# Bower multiple registry URLs in .bowerrc

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, bower

I am looking to define more than one URL in my Bower settings to support the use of a private internal registry as well as the default Heroku registry.

I have tried multiple settings that I have come across, but can't seem to get it working.

There is nothing in the specs that say this is possible, but there is evidence others have gotten this to work.

Can anyone point me in the right direction here?

Is this possible, and if so, how is it done?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Someone at work helped me with this issue. But this is for future searchers.

```
"registry": {
    "search": [
        "http://some.private-bower-registry.com/",
        "https://bower.herokuapp.com"
    ]
}
```