# Polymer - How to put 2 url to registry -> search

Tags: polymer, bower

This is the bowerrc file. I want to search in 2 urls for the polymer components. Is it possible to do that? Neither of the url is local.

```
{
    "registry": {
    "search": [
                "url1",
                "url2"
            ]
    },

"strict-ssl" : false,
"resolvers" : [
    "bower-art-resolver"
],
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bower multiple registry URLs in .bowerrc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24170145/bower-multiple-registry-urls-in-bowerrc)

Comment: It doesn't work for me